# What does Accelerator say to Dark Matter at the end of their fight?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

After Dark Matter's defeat, he stabs Yomikawa to further hurt Accelerator, which causes Accelerator to sprout his black wings and then tell him something in angel language.

The English translation says:

> “—yjrpEVILqw”

What does he say in Japanese though? I tried finding the raw but couldn't, and my Japanese-fu isn't that good. Anyone familiar enough knows what he says there?

Comment: I think it might be nice to edit the title of this question so that it doesn't contain spoilers - maybe something like "What does Accelerator say to Dark Matter at the end of their fight?".

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: In the English Dub, I thought you hear him say "Kill, Kill, Kill, Kill, Kill".  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @estebanrules The battle between Accelerator and Dark Matter was not shown in the anime.

Comment: @estebanrules You're probably thinking of the thing near the end of Index II where Accelerator fights Kihara Amata.

Comment: Ok yes, I'm sorry.  Where is that battle shown?  The manga or light novel?

Comment: In the light novel (very close after the anime finishes too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「——ｙｊｒｐ悪ｑｗ」

Volume 15 (Old Testament), chapter *Dark_Matter*, section 4 (p. 320).

[悪 (あく / *aku*) means "evil"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%82%AA). The surrounding letters don't appear to gain any additional meaning in Japanese - they're probably just gibberish.